# C++: What is the printf() format spec for "float"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, format, printf

C++: What is the `printf()` format spec for `float`? (Visual C++)

It used to be that I used `%g` for `float` and `%lg` for `double`.

It looks like the spec changed and `float` is undefined and `double` is `%g`.

I have bits in memory that I am printing out so casting is not an option.

Is there a way that I can print out `float` values using `printf()` ?

**Update:**

This code was written for unit testing generic C++ libs used on an embedded system. 
Here's what I had to do to get the `float` to work. 
The code is in a template function:

```
template <typename T,typename TTYP,typename Ttyp,int bits,bool IsSigned> 
Error testMatrixT() 
{ ...
```

Here is a code snip:

```
if (typeid(Ttyp) == typeid(float)) {    
    float64 c = *(float32*)&Tp(row,col);
    float64 a1 = *(float32*)&Arg1(row,col);
    float64 a2 = *(float32*)&Arg2(row,col);
    float64 e = *(float32*)&Exp(row,col);
    m_b = (c == e);
    _snprintf(m_acDiag, sizeof(m_acDiag)-1
        , "add(Arg1,Arg2): arg1=%g, arg2=%g, Expected=%g, Actual=%g, Result: %s"
        , a1, a2, e, c, BOOL_PF(m_b));
} else {
    ...
```

Pretty ugly isn't it? Using floats as args give bad output. Maybe due to using `_snprintf()` ?
Years ago I would use `%lg` and it would be OK. Not anymore.

Comment: This is the 3rd or 4th question I've seen, in as many days, about printing a float!

Comment: You didn't mention what happens if you use %g. But %g is not the default for float anyway.

Comment: @steve: `%g` works for float, since it's promoted to double.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

double and float use the same format specifiers with [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) (`%a`, `%e`, `%f`, and `%g`).  This is because `printf` is a variadic function.  Any float arguments are implicitly promoted to double before the call; you can't actually pass a float to `printf`.

Answer (score 5):

To the question in title: There is none / "%f"

To the question in message body: Yes and no.

`printf` is a variadic function. All `float` arguments are automatically promoted to `double`s. You print a float by passing it to printf, but no float actually reaches the printf function.

Answer (score 3):

Others have pointed out the format for printing float using `printf`, but, since you're using C++, my suggestion is to avoid this completely.

Use C++ streams instead, you don't have to worry about format specifiers then. It is also type safe, while `printf` isn't.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  float f = 1.234;
  std::cout << f << std::endl;
}
```

If you have an array of bytes containing a float, `memcpy` it into a float variable and use the above code.

Comment: I ended up using streams, but I think this is a temporary solution since I am sure we will eventually run this on an embedded platform without STL support. It looks to me that floats are deprecated since there is no format spec for it and it doesn't work as an arg to printf unless I cast it to a double.

Answer (score 3):

`%g` has always been the correct format for either float or double (since float arguments are promoted to double for variadic functions like `printf`).

`%lg` was added as a synonym for `%g` (in C99, I don't know when or whether C++ adopted it), probably for better symmetry with the `*scanf` family.

`$Lg` is for long double.

You can replace `g` with `f` or `e` in the above, depending on what output format you want.

Comment: On many systems C++ uses the same runtime as C so if the C library uses C99 standard, so does C++.

Comment: @user877329: True -- but there are still C libraries that don't support C99 (Microsoft, for example, if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 2):

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

%f  Decimal floating point  392.65

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("float: %f", floatValue);
```

or if you want exponential notation:

```
printf("float: %e", floatValue);
```

Comment: Or if you want either fixed-point or exponential: `printf("float: %g", floatValue);`