# How to use printf to view float type variables?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: What is the printf() format spec for “float”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197589/c-what-is-the-printf-format-spec-for-float)

I am new to C++ , and Use the classic Borland Turbo C++

with the graphics initialized , when i use printf the following way, it shows value 0. but when i use cout the correct value is displayed

```
float x=10;
printf("%d",x);   // displays 0
cout<<x;        // displays 10
```

Comment: Also try a web-search for "printf format specifiers" or similar...

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? It's a valid question!

Comment: I'm guessing "does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `%f` modifier to display floating-point values with `printf`:

```
printf("%f", x);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `%f` instead.

`%d` is for integers. Consider reading this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: As an FYI, I would suggest not using cplusplus.com as a reference.  They've historically had some inaccuracies in their API docs, though it's possible that they've fixed things up by now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print two decimals, you should use:

```
Printf("%2f",var);
```